# sankeynetwork not showing the expeced results

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a sankey diagram using the R package "networkD3", but the result is not as expected. The total value of "expenditure" should be equal the sum of the nodes to the left (as well as the nodes on the right), but the left nodes only amount to 2/3 of the expenditure

```
library(networkD3)

nodes <- structure(list(STO = c("D21", "D31", "P1", "P11", "P12", "P13", 
"B1N", "P2", "P51c", "Expenditure")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

links <- structure(list(Source = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 9, 9), Target = c(9, 
9, 9, 2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8), VALUE = c(38415.22308114, -17146.81020189, 
1769578.74087679, 1647394.387995, 8271.16365114771, 113913.189230644, 
1790847.15375604, 1790847.15375604, 1790847.15375604)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

sankeyNetwork(links, nodes, Source = "Source",
                   Target = "Target", Value = "VALUE", NodeID = "STO")
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Cheers

Renger

Comment: How exactly do you expect the diagram to look? The total flow from the right to the expenditure bar in the middle is 5372541.462 (the total of the links from B1N, P2 and P51c), the flow from the left has a height of 1790847.152 (the sum of the links from D21, D31 and P1, although it is strange that D31 has a negative link value). This is as specified in your distance list `links`. Is that not correct?

Answer (score 1):

The diagram displays the information you have entered.

So you either need to recalculate the `VALUE` so that your nodes that link to `Expenditure` match your expected sum or your need to add or adjust the linkages so that you have the right nodes with the correct amount linking to `Expenditure`.

With your example code and the data below you can see that node `C` has inbound links with value 5 and 10 but the outbound link has the value 20 which sets the displayed `C` value to 20.

```r
nodes <- data.frame(
  STO = c("A","B","C","D")
)

links <- data.frame(
  Source = c(0,1,2),
  Target = c(2,2,3),
  VALUE = c(5,10,20)
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the wrong data :-(  instead of looking at links. The negative value are subsidies, the others are normal expenditure/income values. But I have made it positive